# booting into chrome OS after Ubuntu is default

Tags: chromeos

So, I have successfully loaded Chrubuntu 14.04 on my chromebook and managed to set it as the default. However, I have a need to access the Chrome OS, and I don't know to boot back into Chrome. I can only seem to find directions on how to make Ubuntu the default.

Thanks and cheers, 
ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 1 /dev/mmcblk0
```

Then reboot.

[(Source)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ecBvOTJzA4)